# Разрешение зависимостей Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, зависимости

Есть проект с такими зависимостями

```
+--A 1.1
+--B
   \-- A 1.0
```

Т.е. библиотека `A` включена в проект дважды. Причем разных версий.

Сейчас при компиляции проекта я получаю ошибки `Duplicate class`. Как правильно исправлять такие ошибки? Убрать из проекта непосредственную зависимость `A 1.1` и использовать версию 1.0? Или можно указать сборщику проигнорировать включаемую 1.0 и использовать 1.1?

Comment: Использовать `1.0` - лишить себя исправлений, нововведений версии 1.1. Форсировать 1.1 - чревато багами в `B`, так как она не тестировалась с этой версией. Что из этого лучше - выбор за вами. Лучший вариант, но не всегда возможный - обновить `B`, чтобы она использовала `A 1.1`.

Comment: @woesss B не моя и используется последняя версия. Все плюсы и минусы не понятны и так. Как я понимаю, использовать две разных версии не получится? Как форсировать использование 1.1?